# C# read a JPEG from file and store as an Image

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

How can I read a JPEG on my filesystem and store it as a System.Drawing.Image within my C# code?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
Image i = Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
```

If you need more information, here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx for those not fluent in spansish...

Comment: Oops, sorry. Didn't notice the language.