# Why does Image.FromFile return System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm new to using c# with asp.net ajax so any help is appreciated. I am using `System.Drawing.Image` to get my image's virtual path with `Image.FromFile()` and want to return the image to be set up in my web application. Thanks in advance for any response!

I have created a physical path then converted it to a virtual path then used `Server.MapPath` to get the equivalent path to assign to my `Image image`.

```
string pImagePath = @"C:\Apps\WebApp.Roll\Images\Profiles\" + item.Value.ToString();
string vImagePath = pImagePath.Replace(@"C:\Apps\WebApp.Roll", "~").Replace(@"\", "/");
Image image = Image.FromFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(vImagePath), true);

#item.value is name of the image file.
```

My path is correct but whenever I debug to see what my `Image image` is, it tells me that my `image` is `System.Drawing.BitMap` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm confused. If you didn't expect the `Image.FromFile()` method to return a memory-loaded bitmap, what did you expect?

Comment: My image is a jpg, do I need to use a converter? Or should I be using Graphics.DrawImage because right now when I load my WebApplication I get back System.Drawing.BitMap.

Comment: @Rae no https://stackoverflow.com/a/330350/1043380

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# read a JPEG from file and store as an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330346/c-sharp-read-a-jpeg-from-file-and-store-as-an-image)

Comment: It's not clear at all from the question what the problem is here. Are you unable to return the `Image`? What error are you getting? Or perhaps you're confusing the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class with the `BMP` file extension? They are two different things, you know. Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8) for more information.

Comment: I have look at this link but I still don't understand why I can't get my image to stay as jpeg?

Comment: @Rae [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=netframework-4.8) is a class, not a file format. It represents the bits that form your image.

Comment: Thank you! @Rufus L

Comment: It's not clear where `item.Value` comes from, but if it's from the browser, beware of [path traversal attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal). Check that the resulting filepath is under the directory that you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of C# code, the class Bitmap refers to any image that uses pixel arranged colors into a map of bits. This is **not** limited to files with the extension .bmp (Windows Bitmap). Examples that are Bitmaps: [JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-bitmaps#graphics-file-formats).

As opposed to image files that contain a set of instructions to build the image such as SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics) or WMF (Windows Metafile Image). These are examples of images that are **not** Bitmaps.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I see now that Bitmap includes JPG. I marked this as the answer as soon as it lets me! is there a way to load my bitmap to an actual image?

Comment: As the documentation shows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap) the class Bitmap overrides the class Image. So any System.Drawing.Bitmap instance will work as the type System.Drawing.Image in any context.

Comment: Thank you @Rhaokiel